# foreach to Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel.foreach

I have a task which runs but I am not satisfied with its speed so i decided to make it into a Parallel.ForEach since its faster, can anyone help me transform this function into a Parallel.ForEach thank you.

```
        private async void run_task()
        {
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            label20.Text = "";
            foreach (var node2 in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                rd node = (rd)node2;
                node.max_chp = await mc(node.link);
                for (int ii = 1; ii <= node.max_chp; ii++)
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = (int)(((decimal)ii / (decimal)node.max_chp) * 100);
                    byte[] data = null;
                    string add;
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.Proxy = null;
                        if (ii == 1)
                        {
                            add = node.link;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            add = node.link + ii.ToString() + ".html";
                        }
                        string tem = await get_pics(add, ii - 1);
                        label20.Text = add;
                        using (Task<byte[]> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<byte[]>(() => dl_data(client, tem), cancellationToken))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                await task;
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                dis_GUI(true, 1);
                                label20.Text = "";
                                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                                pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                                return;
                            }
                            data = task.Result;                                        
                        }
                    }
                    string subPath = node.name;
                    subPath = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(subPath, "[^0-9a-zA-Z.]+", " ");
                    subPath = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(subPath, @"\d+", n => n.Value.PadLeft(3, '0'));
                    string path = Path.Combine(files, subPath);
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, ii.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + ".jpg"), data);
                }
            }
            dis_GUI(true, 1);
            label20.Text = "";
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        }
```

I know my code i badly done but please bare with it.

Comment: I highly recommend you extract small pieces of the logic into separate methods.

Comment: Without an attempt, you won't receive much help.  Your question reads "I want this, and I want you to do it for me"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have code that updates the UI in the foreach statement that you want to convert to parallel.
This is not recommended:
If you do run parallel loops on the UI thread, be careful to avoid updating UI controls from within the loop. Attempting to update UI controls from within a parallel loop that is executing on the UI thread can lead to state corruption, exceptions, delayed updates, and even deadlocks, depending on how the UI update is invoked. In the following example, the parallel loop blocks the UI thread on which it’s executing until all iterations are complete. However, if an iteration of the loop is running on a background thread (as For may do), the call to Invoke causes a message to be submitted to the UI thread and blocks waiting for that message to be processed. Since the UI thread is blocked running the For, the message can never be processed, and the UI thread deadlocks. 
Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you're admitting you need help and that you're newer to programming, I'm going to share with you some best practices instead of writing the code for you.

So, first of all, you should almost never be doing any kind of UI manipulation in parallel loops. When you use `Parallel.ForEach` the items in the collection you are iterating over are not processed sequentially. Notice that you are referencing `progressBar1` in the loop. That's fine for a sequential `for` loop, but when done in parallel multiple threads are trying to update that same object at the same time and in no predictable order. You are going to run into what is called a "race condition" and it's going to do all manner of weird things and probably even make it slower. There is overhead involved in creating and managing threads when doing parallel operations that is non-trivial. For small collections, you're unlikely to get the benefit you're looking for.

In this particular case, you should think about how to write the same thing you're doing in a more efficient way. This will make you a better programmer. It's is common among newer developers to immediately look at parallelizing some iteration that's slow to make it faster, but it's more than likely not the right thing to do and concurrency is no trivial thing to manage.